# How to correctly call getContentResolver() from within an onclick event

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener, illegalstateexception

I have a button with an onclick handler defined like:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ImportCalendar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:onClick="icaltesting"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Import" />
```

Now I have defined the `testing()` function in my activity class and I want to use the 
`getContentResolver()` function to ultimately create a local calendar in my android device.
The code I use is as follows:

```
public void icaltesting(View view) {
    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, "Test");
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "Local Calendar");
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

    calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "Test")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,     CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
        .build();
    Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(calUri, cv);
  }
```

It's the last line that throws an `IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity` and the app force closes. I think I am not calling the `getContentResolver()` function properly. How do I go about this issue?

**Edit 1**
The relevant stack trace is this:

```
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:166)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:136)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:735)
   08-23 20:05:56.580: E/AndroidRuntime(24197):     at com.example.myfirstapp.CalendarTest.icaltesting(CalendarTest.java:117)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you look closely at the stack trace, you'll find another exception. This exception is the root cause.

But in fact this is not important. There is no correct way to call getContentResolver() from an onClick handler. You shouldn't use it on the UI thread at all. Schedule an `AsyncTask` instead.

UPDATE: according to the documentation, you are missing several required fields

> Insert
>
> When inserting a new calendar the following fields must be included:
>
> ACCOUNT_NAME
>
> ACCOUNT_TYPE
>
> NAME
>
> CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME
>
> CALENDAR_COLOR
>
> CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL
>
> OWNER_ACCOUNT

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually trying to implement a dialog and therefore I was doing this initially from an `AsyncTask` only, but that did not work either.I am definitely missing something. The last 2 lines of the stack trace have probably something to do with the contentResolver. The last line corresponds to `Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(calUri, cv);`.